# How to change the trackpad sensitivity on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4

How can I change *only* the trackpad sensitivity on Raspberry Pi 4? My trackpad is very small and I'd like to change the sensitivity on it to make it easier to use.

Comment: I'd think there's something in the DE settings, but if not have a look at `man xset`, there are options there for `mouse` ("applies to most pointing devices") with fields for `acceleration` and `threshold`.  Once you work it out you should be able to put it in an desktop autostart script.

Comment: And how do I change it?

Comment: Maybe `xinput` is better: https://askubuntu.com/a/262891/239729

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, I changed it